# How can I decorate all functions imported from a file?

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

I have created many functions that are divided into different files, now I would like to apply the same decorator for all of them without modifying the files and without applying the decorators one by one.

I have tried to use [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-can-i-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for) written by delnan, but I got no success for imported functions.

About the decorator, it must update a list every time a function within a class is executexecuted with the function arguments and values, just like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154006/update-a-list-every-time-a-function-within-a-class-is-executexecuted-with-the-fu) I asked.

Any suggestions to help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: How are you doing the import? Are you just doing the module, or are you doing individual functions or an `from foo import *` etc...

Comment: Are they just functions or are they methods of classes in the files?

Comment: The imports are done like `from modules import module1` and they are just function inside  files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little bit of introspection ([`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)) and dynamic look-up with [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

First we iterate over all names found in module and [check for objects that look like functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType). After that we simply reassign old function with decorated one.

**main.py:**

```
import types
import functools

def decorate_all_in_module(module, decorator):
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
            setattr(module, name, decorator(obj))

def my_decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

import mymod1
decorate_all_in_module(mymod1, decorator)
```

**mymod1.py**:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)


def g(x, y):
    print(x + y)
```

**Output:**

```
<function f at 0x101e309d8>
2
<function g at 0x101e30a60>
7
```

Process does not goes that smooth if you use star imports (`from mymod import *`). Reason is simple - because all names are in one huge bag and there no differentiation on where they come from, you need a lot of additional tricks to find what exactly you want to patch. But, well, that's why we use namespaces - [because they are one honking great idea](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked fine.

In fact, I asked this question to complete [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154006/update-a-list-every-time-a-function-within-a-class-is-executexecuted-with-the-fu) I had asked. I thought I could solve my problem from this, but it was not the case.
I would like my decorator to save the args and function name every time some function from the imported class is ran.
Could you help me with this new subject?

Comment: You want do decorate all methods of class? Process is fairly similar, you do `dir(class)` and look for methods and not functions. I'm quite sure you can figure that out yourself based on template above.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. 
I have used python as a free tool to replace Matlab, until now I have used it only as a numerical tool. I see I still have a lot to learn, but nothing to take away my will to learn it.
Again, thank you.